# Assimp deletes my new files when I build

Tags: c++, cmake, assimp

I'm trying to implement a custom loader for the Assimp project, following the instructions here:

http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/extend.html

But no matter what I do, when I build the assimp project, my files get deleted. I added my files to the project and to CMakelists.txt, like so:

```
SOURCE_GROUP( X3D FILES ${X3D_SRCS})

SET( X3D_SRCS
    X3DLoader.cpp
    X3DLoader.h
)
```

Below:

```
SET( assimp_src
    #...
    ${Ply_SRCS}
    ${X3D_SRCS}
    ${Q3D_SRCS}
    #...
)
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up when defining the source group, it was upside down (first `SET`, then `SOURCE_GROUP`). It goes like this:

```
SET( X3D_SRCS
    X3DLoader.cpp
    X3DLoader.h
)
SOURCE_GROUP( X3D FILES ${X3D_SRCS})
```